# Getting HTML elements on the required place on the webpage

Tags: html, css

```js
//declaring all varaibles
   var scoreOfUser = 0; //user's score
   var scoreOfComp = 0; //computer's score
   var scoreOfDraws = 0; // number of draws
   var user = ""; var comp = ""; //variables holding the user's and computer's choices

   var randomizer = function(){ //randomly selects from among rock, paper or scissors 
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
    if(num === 0){
     comp = "ROCK"; 
     document.getElementById("compChoice").innerHTML = "ROCK";
    }
    else if(num === 1){
     comp = "PAPER"; 
     document.getElementById("compChoice").innerHTML = "PAPER";
    }
    else if(num === 2){
     comp = "SCISSORS"; 
     document.getElementById("compChoice").innerHTML = "SCISSORS";
    }
    else {return true;}
   }

   var playRock = function(){ //when user chooses rock
    user = "ROCK";
    document.getElementById("userChoice").innerHTML = "ROCK";
    randomizer();
    if(user === comp){
     scoreOfDraws++; 
     document.getElementById("drawScore").innerHTML = scoreOfDraws; 
     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "It's a Draw!";
    }
    else if(comp === "SCISSORS"){
     scoreOfUser++; 
     document.getElementById("userScore").innerHTML = scoreOfUser; 
     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You crushed the Computer under a large rock!";
    }
    else{
     scoreOfComp++; 
     document.getElementById("compScore").innerHTML = scoreOfComp; 
     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "The Computer blocked you and blew you away!";
    }
   }

   var playPaper = function(){ //when user chooses paper
    user = "PAPER";
    document.getElementById("userChoice").innerHTML = "PAPER";
    randomizer();
    if(user === comp){
     scoreOfDraws++; 
     document.getElementById("drawScore").innerHTML = scoreOfDraws; 
     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "It's a Draw!";
    }
    else if(comp === "ROCK"){
     scoreOfUser++; 
     document.getElementById("userScore").innerHTML = scoreOfUser; 
     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You blocked the Computer and blew it away!";
    }
    else{
     scoreOfComp++; 
     document.getElementById("compScore").innerHTML = scoreOfComp; 
     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "The Computer finished you with its quick and sharp scissors!";
    }
   }

   var playScissors = function(){ //when user chooses scissors
    user = "SCISSORS";
    document.getElementById("userChoice").innerHTML = "SCISSORS";
    randomizer();
    if(user === comp){
     scoreOfDraws++; 
     document.getElementById("drawScore").innerHTML = scoreOfDraws; 
     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "It's a Draw!";
    }
    else if(comp === "PAPER"){
     scoreOfUser++; 
     document.getElementById("userScore").innerHTML = scoreOfUser; 
     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You finished the Computer with your quick and sharp scissors!";
    }
    else{
     scoreOfComp++; 
     document.getElementById("compScore").innerHTML = scoreOfComp; 
     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "The Computer crushed you under a large rock!";
    }
   }

   var reset = function(){ //resets the game's scores
    scoreOfUser = 0; scoreOfComp = 0; scoreOfDraws = 0;
    document.getElementById("userScore").innerHTML = scoreOfUser;
    document.getElementById("compScore").innerHTML = scoreOfComp;
    document.getElementById("drawScore").innerHTML = scoreOfDraws;
    document.getElementById("userChoice").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("compChoice").innerHTML = "";
    console.log("Game reset");

   }
```

```css
#theHead{
    font-family: Chalkduster, Copperplate Gothic Bold;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: gold;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    border: 3px solid goldenrod;
   }

   .playButtons{
    background-color:gold;
    border: 2px solid goldenrod;
    border-radius: 50px;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
   }

   img{
    height: 130px;
    width: 130px;
    margin: 10px;
   }

   table{
    border: 2px solid goldenrod;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-family: Chalkduster;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    
   }

   td{
    border: 2px solid goldenrod;
    font-variant: small-caps;
   }

   #resetButton{
    font-family: Comic Sans, Chalkduster, Copperplate Gothic Bold;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    background-color: gold;
    font-size: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px;
    border: 2px solid goldenrod;
    border-radius: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100px;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Rock-Paper-Scissors</title>
  </head>
 <body>
  <div id="theHead">
    Rock-Paper-Scissors
  </div>

  <div style="font-size: 27px; font-family: Chalkduster, Copperplate Gothic Bold; font-variant: small-caps; margin-bottom: 20px">Click the buttons to make your choice: Rock, Paper or Scissors.</div>

  <div class="playButtons" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor = 'goldenrod'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor = 'gold'" onclick="playRock()"><img src="https://img.clipartfest.com/95f4daba36ac7e8a1b142ef660141834_rock-music-clipart-free-rock-clipart-transparent-background_2400-2249.png"/></div>
  <div class="playButtons" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor = 'goldenrod'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor = 'gold'" onclick="playPaper()"><img src="https://img.clipartfest.com/5cede8303a5e9822a475bb8958c82fe0_stack-of-papers-clip-art-at-clipart-pile-of-papers-no-background_282-300.png"/></div>
  <div class="playButtons" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor = 'goldenrod'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor = 'gold'" onclick="playScissors()"><img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/scissors/scissors_PNG28.png"/></div>

  <br/>

  <div style="font-size: 27px; font-family: Chalkduster, Copperplate Gothic Bold; font-variant: small-caps;" class="sentences">You chose <span id="userChoice"></span>.</div>
  <div style="font-size: 27px; font-family: Chalkduster, Copperplate Gothic Bold; font-variant: small-caps;" class="sentences">Computer chose <span id="compChoice"></span>.</div>
  <div style="font-size: 27px; font-family: Chalkduster, Copperplate Gothic Bold; font-variant: small-caps;" Id="result" class="sentences"></div>

  <table title="Scorecard">
   <tr><th colspan="3">ScoreCard</th></tr>
   <tr>
    <td>You</td>
    <td>Computer</td>
    <td>Draws</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td id="userScore">0</td>
    <td id="compScore">0</td>
    <td id="drawScore">0</td>
   </tr>
  </table>

  <div id="resetButton" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor = 'goldenrod'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor = 'gold'" onclick="reset()">Reset</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've made a small Rock-Paper-Scissors game using HTML, CSS and JS. If you run my code on your on computer/laptop as a separate webpage, you would notice that the *scorecard* and the sentences which show user's choice, computer's choice and the result of a round all are places next to the gameplay buttons(the rock, paper and scissors buttons).  To place the game buttons next to each other I have applied the css float: left; property to them. I want to get the scorecard and those sentences under the buttons but I am unable to. I've tried to put property position: absolute; to the rest of the things other than buttons, but to no use. If I remove the float property from the buttons, the scorecard and the sentences go correctly under the buttons, but the buttons also get placed one below the other(but I want the buttons side by side). Please suggest a solution. Also, please run the snippet in full page.

Comment: Have you considered taking a look at CSS `flexbox`? It definitely makes tasks like this a million times easier

Comment: @EmilBækdahl I'll try it for sure. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Great, @Frost. CSS Tricks have a great guide: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a `clear:both` somewhere such as

```js
//declaring all varaibles
   var scoreOfUser = 0; //user's score
   var scoreOfComp = 0; //computer's score
   var scoreOfDraws = 0; // number of draws
   var user = ""; var comp = ""; //variables holding the user's and computer's choices

   var randomizer = function(){ //randomly selects from among rock, paper or scissors 
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
    if(num === 0){
     comp = "ROCK"; 
     document.getElementById("compChoice").innerHTML = "ROCK";
    }
    else if(num === 1){
     comp = "PAPER"; 
     document.getElementById("compChoice").innerHTML = "PAPER";
    }
    else if(num === 2){
     comp = "SCISSORS"; 
     document.getElementById("compChoice").innerHTML = "SCISSORS";
    }
    else {return true;}
   }

   var playRock = function(){ //when user chooses rock
    user = "ROCK";
    document.getElementById("userChoice").innerHTML = "ROCK";
    randomizer();
    if(user === comp){
     scoreOfDraws++; 
     document.getElementById("drawScore").innerHTML = scoreOfDraws; 
     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "It's a Draw!";
    }
    else if(comp === "SCISSORS"){
     scoreOfUser++; 
     document.getElementById("userScore").innerHTML = scoreOfUser; 
     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You crushed the Computer under a large rock!";
    }
    else{
     scoreOfComp++; 
     document.getElementById("compScore").innerHTML = scoreOfComp; 
     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "The Computer blocked you and blew you away!";
    }
   }

   var playPaper = function(){ //when user chooses paper
    user = "PAPER";
    document.getElementById("userChoice").innerHTML = "PAPER";
    randomizer();
    if(user === comp){
     scoreOfDraws++; 
     document.getElementById("drawScore").innerHTML = scoreOfDraws; 
     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "It's a Draw!";
    }
    else if(comp === "ROCK"){
     scoreOfUser++; 
     document.getElementById("userScore").innerHTML = scoreOfUser; 
     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You blocked the Computer and blew it away!";
    }
    else{
     scoreOfComp++; 
     document.getElementById("compScore").innerHTML = scoreOfComp; 
     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "The Computer finished you with its quick and sharp scissors!";
    }
   }

   var playScissors = function(){ //when user chooses scissors
    user = "SCISSORS";
    document.getElementById("userChoice").innerHTML = "SCISSORS";
    randomizer();
    if(user === comp){
     scoreOfDraws++; 
     document.getElementById("drawScore").innerHTML = scoreOfDraws; 
     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "It's a Draw!";
    }
    else if(comp === "PAPER"){
     scoreOfUser++; 
     document.getElementById("userScore").innerHTML = scoreOfUser; 
     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You finished the Computer with your quick and sharp scissors!";
    }
    else{
     scoreOfComp++; 
     document.getElementById("compScore").innerHTML = scoreOfComp; 
     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "The Computer crushed you under a large rock!";
    }
   }

   var reset = function(){ //resets the game's scores
    scoreOfUser = 0; scoreOfComp = 0; scoreOfDraws = 0;
    document.getElementById("userScore").innerHTML = scoreOfUser;
    document.getElementById("compScore").innerHTML = scoreOfComp;
    document.getElementById("drawScore").innerHTML = scoreOfDraws;
    document.getElementById("userChoice").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("compChoice").innerHTML = "";
    console.log("Game reset");

   }
```

```css
#theHead{
    font-family: Chalkduster, Copperplate Gothic Bold;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: gold;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    border: 3px solid goldenrod;
   }

   .playButtons{
    background-color:gold;
    border: 2px solid goldenrod;
    border-radius: 50px;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
   }

   img{
    height: 130px;
    width: 130px;
    margin: 10px;
   }

   table{
    border: 2px solid goldenrod;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-family: Chalkduster;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    
   }

   td{
    border: 2px solid goldenrod;
    font-variant: small-caps;
   }

   #resetButton{
    font-family: Comic Sans, Chalkduster, Copperplate Gothic Bold;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    background-color: gold;
    font-size: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px;
    border: 2px solid goldenrod;
    border-radius: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100px;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Rock-Paper-Scissors</title>
  </head>
 <body>
  <div id="theHead">
    Rock-Paper-Scissors
  </div>

  <div style="font-size: 27px; font-family: Chalkduster, Copperplate Gothic Bold; font-variant: small-caps; margin-bottom: 20px">Click the buttons to make your choice: Rock, Paper or Scissors.</div>

  <div class="playButtons" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor = 'goldenrod'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor = 'gold'" onclick="playRock()"><img src="https://img.clipartfest.com/95f4daba36ac7e8a1b142ef660141834_rock-music-clipart-free-rock-clipart-transparent-background_2400-2249.png"/></div>
  <div class="playButtons" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor = 'goldenrod'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor = 'gold'" onclick="playPaper()"><img src="https://img.clipartfest.com/5cede8303a5e9822a475bb8958c82fe0_stack-of-papers-clip-art-at-clipart-pile-of-papers-no-background_282-300.png"/></div>
  <div class="playButtons" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor = 'goldenrod'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor = 'gold'" onclick="playScissors()"><img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/scissors/scissors_PNG28.png"/></div>

  <br style="clear:both"/>

  <div style="font-size: 27px; font-family: Chalkduster, Copperplate Gothic Bold; font-variant: small-caps;" class="sentences">You chose <span id="userChoice"></span>.</div>
  <div style="font-size: 27px; font-family: Chalkduster, Copperplate Gothic Bold; font-variant: small-caps;" class="sentences">Computer chose <span id="compChoice"></span>.</div>
  <div style="font-size: 27px; font-family: Chalkduster, Copperplate Gothic Bold; font-variant: small-caps;" Id="result" class="sentences"></div>

  <table title="Scorecard">
   <tr><th colspan="3">ScoreCard</th></tr>
   <tr>
    <td>You</td>
    <td>Computer</td>
    <td>Draws</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td id="userScore">0</td>
    <td id="compScore">0</td>
    <td id="drawScore">0</td>
   </tr>
  </table>

  <div id="resetButton" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor = 'goldenrod'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor = 'gold'" onclick="reset()">Reset</div>
  </body>
</html>
```